# Exclude column 0 (rownames) column from data frame and csv output

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, write.table

Hell all,

How do I go about excluding the zero column, or rownames column from a data frame or csv output?

```
df <- df[,c(1,2,3,4,5]
drops <- c(0)
df <- df[,!(names(df) %in% drops)]
write.csv(df,'Forecast Values.csv')
```

I tried the above but the rownames column still carries over into both "df" and the csv file, and I particularly want it excluded in the csv. Also of note, variable 'drops' reads as a value of zero, as opposed to the column zero.

Comment: there is no "column 0" in a R data.frame. read `?write.csv`, you'll see a parameter for including or not the `row.names`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drop the `rownames` of a `dataframe` by simply setting them to null. They're null by default (see `?data.frame`), but sometimes they get set by various functions:

```
# Create a sample dataframe with row.names
a_data_frame <- data.frame(letters = c("a", "b", "c"), 
                           numbers = c(1, 2, 3), 
                           row.names = c("Row1", "Row2", "Row3"));
# View it
a_data_frame;
>        letters numbers
>Row1       a       1
>Row2       b       2
>Row3       c       3

# Use rownames() to set them to new value, which is null in this case
rownames(a_data_frame) <- NULL;

# View it again
a_data_frame;
>     letters numbers
>1       a       1
>2       b       2
>3       c       3
```

Note that `NULL` `rownames` show up as an incremental count when printed, but no longer exist in the `a_data_frame` `data frame` object, so when handled by another function like `write.csv`, any `rownames` that you see are created by the function, not taken from the `data frame` object itself.

As mentioned by the previous poster (see `?write.csv`), you can specify `row.names=FALSE` in your `write.csv` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the rows to **NULL** like so:
`row.names(df) <- NULL`

You can also rename the rows if you prefer:
`row.names(df) <- c("row_1","row_2", etc...)`